# Google Spreadsheet set unique id or metadata for cell or row

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

is it possible to attach some hidden ID or metadata for cell or row in Google Spreadsheet so that i.e. I would able to move my cell anywhere on my sheet but still get text from this cell (wherever it is located: A:2 or B:10 or Z:955) in my javascript function?

I just want something like this:

```
function getCellValueWithID(id) { // not INDIRECT('A2')
   console.log( this.val() );
}

getCellValueWithID("my_cell"); // Outputs "Hello"
```

[image]

Comment: You could give the cell a named range.  Refer to the cell by the range name, not by it's location.

Comment: From the "Data" menu, choose "Named Ranges"  Add a new range name.  Enter a range name or use the default.  Use the code:  `function getRangeByName() {
  var r;
  
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('NamedRange1');
  
  Logger.log(r.getValue())
}`   Even if the cell is moved, the code will still get the value in the moved cell, because the range name stays with the cell when it is moved.

Comment: @LioraHaydont Actually, it is. See answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As of Oct 2017 you can add metadata to your spreadsheeet using Developer Metadata as documented at the link below:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata

To do this from Apps Script you have to leverage the Advanced Sheet service referenced at the following link:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets

Also, here's a tutorial on the topic:

http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/totallyunscripted/sheetsdevelopermetaadv

Comment: I believe you don't need to use the Advanced Sheet service to do it from Apps Script, you can use the [DeveloperMetadata](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata) class.

Comment: @flawyte At the time I wrote this answer the DeveloperMetaData class was not yet available in the built-in Spreadsheet service ([see Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2018#november_14_2018)).

Comment: Important callout: in 2021, it still can't be set on individual cells:
`Exception: Adding developer metadata to arbitrary ranges is not currently supported. Developer metadata may only be added to the top-level spreadsheet, an individual sheet, or an entire row or column.`
(This is mentioned if you get far enough down in that tutorial)